# Angular JS Doesnt Seem to work, newbie

Tags: angularjs

i got one sample app from net, which i tried to implement, but it doesn't seem to work, below is the code of app, please help me by fixing it and suggest me how can i make it more better. i am a newbie to Angular.

Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/eGzZg/

```
<div id="main" ng-controller="contactDetails">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="newcontact.name"/>
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="newcontact.email"/>
      <label>Phone No</label>
      <input type="text" name="phno" ng-model="newcontact.phno"/>
      <input type="hidden" ng-model="newcontact.id" />
      <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="saveContact()" />
  <div id="table">
    <div id="thead">
      <span>Name</span>
      <span>Email</span>
      <span>Phone No</span>
      <span>Action</span>
    </div>
    <div id="tbody" ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
      <span> {{contact.name}}  </span>
      <span> {{contact.email}} </span>
      <span> {{contact.phno}}  </span>
      <span> <a href='#' ng-click="edit(contact.id)">Edit</a></span>
      <span> <a href='#' ng-click="delete(contact.id)">Delete</a></span>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>


<script>
var uid = 0;
function contactDetails($scope) {
  //$scope.contacts = [{ id : null, 'name':null, 'phno':null }];
  $scope.contacts = [
        { id:0, 'name': 'Viral', 
          'email':'hello@gmail.com', 
          'phno': '123-2343-44'
        }
    ];
  $scope.saveContact = function(){
    alert('sd');  
    for( i in $scope.contacts){
      if($scope.contacts[i].id == $scope.newcontact.id || ($scope.contacts[i].name == $scope.newcontact.name && $scope.contacts[i].phno == $scope.newcontact.phno)){
        $scope.contacts[i] = $scope.newcontact;
      }else{
        $scope.contacts.id = ++uid;
        $scope.contacts.push($scope.newcontact); 
      }
      $scope.newcontact = {};
    } 
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: How do you expect that to work? Angular is not even loaded. Use plunker which have a angular template to play with it.

Answer (score 1):

don't forget to actually include angular and also you forgot ng-app

```
<body ng-app>
```

[here ya go](http://jsfiddle.net/eGzZg/1/)

Comment: Thanks Buddy!! I have one problem here, check the code in jsfiddle, problem is initially i am making the contacts objects as null because of which extra edit and delete tags u see always on the beginning , how to get rid of it ?
http://jsfiddle.net/eGzZg/4/

Comment: I am not really understanding your question. I highly recommend that you first go through the AngularJS tutorial here: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial (if you haven't already).

Then go through all 25 days of this: http://www.ng-newsletter.com/advent2013/#!/ 

I promise after going through both, you will be an angular expert in no time.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `$scope.contacts = [{ id : null, 'name':null, 'phno':null }];`

to   `$scope.contacts = [];`

Even if you set the properties of the contact elements to null, it still has a single element and thats why there is no text, but the buttons are appearing when the page is loaded.